# How to install multiple ubuntu images in the same host via docker?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-image

I need to do a multi-thread running via a data analysis software in a host.
But I find if I use multithread directly, the results derived have conflicts with each other. Probably it is because common parameters are shared.

So I want to install the software many times and run the softwares simultaneously.  I can pull ubuntu via

```
docker run -it ubuntu bash
```

and install the software in this ubuntu.

But how to pull ubuntu from the repository many times? I need different ubuntus which are really installed in the host. Now once the first ubuntu is installed, if I use `docker run -it ubuntu bash` again, just a new image is generated, not a real system that occupies disk space.

**Containers are separated, but if the software is installed only one time in the host, how to avoid common-parameter problem? How to really install the software 5 times in the host?**

Comment: This isn't clear - you are free to run (via `docker run`) multiple containers simultaneously.  So I'm not sure what problem you're describing here?  (I'm not sure what you mean by "a new image is generated, not a real system that occupies disk space".)

Comment: @oliver Once the software is installed, it will appear in the host, say, in/var/lib/docker/overlay2/....If it does not appear in that directory and no new disk space is occupied, I am worried about the common parameter problem. I do not want to run the softwares just in different containers. I want the softwares really installed in the host.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense - if you want stuff to be "really installed in the host" then why are you using Docker?

Comment: @Oliver Dependencies will be chaos if the software is installed many times in the host.

Comment: So then what is your question?

Comment: @Oliver How to install ubuntu many times via `docker run -it ubuntu bash`. Then every ubuntu can have its own version of the software.

Comment: Note that a Docker container doesn't *install* anything.  If you want multiple independent Ubuntu containers, then you need to run multiple containers.

Comment: @oliver can you make it more clear via  docker commands? Do i need `docker commit`?

Answer (score 4):

You can either:

- create a Dockerfile for each set of applications you want to install and build a named/tagged image. This will be tidier and easy to replicate.
- Or, name the containers you are creating:

  docker run --name app1 ubuntu /bin/bash

  docker run --name app2 ubuntu /bin/bash

Then you can save images of them with *commit*.  Also start, stop and enter if necessary.

Comment: There is only one app. The first way means many images which contain the software will be made,right? But they do not occupy new disk space.

Comment: I want a way that every ubuntu is completely independent of each other. Then every software is independent.

Comment: Both ways are independent (applications, configurations, file system in general). They will only share disk space as long as files are not modified, due to docker images layer mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

A Docker/OCI image is an immutable object. Running an image as a container does not modify the image, the container layers any file system changes on top of the image. Each container you run is a seperate entity, running in its own namespace with it's own file system changes. Each container has unique ID reference.

In most cases you would create a `Dockerfile` to describe all the common software installation and configuration you require on top of ubuntu.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install mydeps
```

Which you build and tag

```
$ docker build -t me/myapp .
```

Then when ever you run the image, a new container will be created seperate from the image and seperate from any other containers that are running:

```
$ docker run -ti me/myapp bash
root@28cfd02a55b1:/# echo test > /test
root@28cfd02a55b1:/# cat /test
test
```

In a second container the file won't exist

```
$ docker run -ti me/myapp bash
root@39584fb744a9:/# cat /test
cat: /test: No such file or directory
```

On the host you can see each container instance with a `docker ps`:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
39584fb744a9        me/myapp                     "bash"                   21 seconds ago       Up 20 seconds                                kind_brattain
28cfd02a55b1        me/myapp                     "bash"                   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                            blissful_thompson
```

Comment: So if fact, the app only needs to be installed one time? When I run the app in different containers,  how to avoid common-parameter problem? Is there a way I can really install the app 5 times? 'really' means the app really occupies disk space in the host.

Comment: Yes, app can be installed once in the base image. Each container gets it own view of the data (or parameters) and then any changes in the container will be local to that container only. Why do you need 5 installs? If you make the container specific changes in a container they won't impact each other

Comment: Two questions here. The data are in the host. All containers need to mount the data and process their own independent data. No problem, right?      Any way, I still want to know how to install the app 5 times in 5 ubuntus, not in 5 containers. If there is a way, please let me know.

Comment: If the data is read only you can mount it read only into all containers. If it's read write you will need a copy for each container unless your app does some type of file locking.

Comment: You could do something like create a base `Dockerfile` with all the common stuff, build and tag that as `me/myinstall`. Then create 5 Dockerfiles `FROM me/myinstall` with the custom app installs and tag the images as  `me/myapp[1-5]`.

Comment: I have tried your way. The 5 Dockerfiles do not occupy new disk space. Could I pull 5 systems from the repository and install the 5 systems independently?

Comment: Maybe ask new specific question with details of your build and the layout you are trying to achieve. It appears you are getting stuck on a detail that I think docker could take care of for you.

Comment: Thanks. My questions are 'Containers are separated, but if the software is installed only one time in the host, how to avoid common-parameter problem? How to really install the software 5 times in the host?' Probably I should not worry about the 1st problem. But, any way, how to really install the software 5 times in the host?

Comment: @questionhang - as I think I mentioned above, running Docker containers does install anything on the host.  You cannot "install the software 5 times on the host" by using Docker.  But to be clear, Docker containers also don't share anything, so whatever you mean by the "common parameter problem" will likely be solved by running multiple Docker containers.